# Wrap every 3 columns in a row

Tags: php

I'd like to wrap 3 columns in a row, followed by another 3 columns in a row, and so on. Is my modulus operator the issue or something else? Thanks.

```
<?php if( have_rows('service') ): ?>

            <?php while ( have_rows('service') ) : the_row(); ?>

            <?php if($counter % 3 === 0) :    echo '<div class="row"'; endif; ?>

                        <div class="col grid_4_of_12 price-container team_member">
                            <span class="price"><?php the_sub_field('service_price'); ?></span>
                              <img src="<?php the_sub_field('service_image'); ?>" />
                              <h3 style="font-size:18px;" class="member_name"><?php the_sub_field('service_name'); ?></h3>
                              <p><?php the_sub_field('service_description'); ?></p>
                       </div>
                       <?php $counter++; if($counter % 3 === 0) :  echo '</div>'; endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else :  ?>
            <?php echo 'No Rows Found'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Try `==` in place of `===`  and maybe put `$counter++;` after `echo '</div>'` ? Because of your current logic, the opening and closing divs may not match because you are checking for different conditions. Value of `$counter` for the opening div will not be same as that for the closing div.

Comment: Actually, I think you need to move the `$counter++` statement outside of if statement altogether. You want to increment the `$counter` variable irrespective of the modulo condition being met or not.

Comment: The logic is a little bit obscure but it does work! First time, the counter is 0 and it echoes the opening div.  On the 3rd pass, counter becomes 3 after the ++ and echoes the final div.

Answer (score 2):

The first div appears to be missing the closing bracket. Change to...

```
<?php if($counter % 3 === 0) :    echo '<div class="row">'; endif; ?>
```

Tip: Always look at the HTML source code that you produce while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach($sections as $section):

//if the result of the modulo operation is 0, open new row
if($count % 3 == 0): ?>
 <div class="row">
<?php endif ?>

// Display your inner divs here

<?php if($count % 3 == 2): ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
<?php $count++; 
endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your div before incrementing `$counter`

```
<?php $counter++; if($counter % 3 === 0) :  echo '</div>'; endif; ?>
```

should change to

```
<?php if($counter % 3 === 0) :  echo '</div>'; endif; $counter++;  ?>
```

Comment: The loop logic is a bit obscure but the increment should go before the div.  1st time into the loop, $counter=0 and it echos the opening div. $counter increments and the closing loop is not echoed. On the third trip through the loop, $counter increments to 3, and the closing div prints.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    // add a counter
    $counter = 1;
    ?>
      <?php $query = new WP_Query(array("post_type" => "services","posts_per_page" => -1 )); ?>
      <?php if($query->have_posts()):?>
    <div class="row">
      <?php while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="service-media"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div>
        <div class="service-desc">
          <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php if($counter % 3 === 0) :?>
        </div><div class="row">
      <?php endif; ?>
     <?php $counter++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    //Wrap every 3 elements with div.row
    $index = 1;

    foreach( $sub_pages as $sub_page ) {

        if ($index % 3 == 1 || $index == 1) { // beginning of the row or first
            echo '<div class="row">';
        }

        echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';

        echo $sub_page->post_title;
        echo $sub_page->post_excerpt;

        echo '</div><!-- .col -->';

        if ($index % 3 == 0 || $index == count($sub_pages)) { // end of the row or last
            echo '</div><!-- .row -->';
        }

        $index++;
    }
    //Wrap every 5 elements using array_chunk():
    $chunks = array_chunk($original, 5);
    foreach ($chunks as $each_chunk) {
         // echo out as an unordered list
     }
    ?>
```